# How to make a smart precharge circuit

Tags: high-voltage, isolation, pre-charge

I want to build a circuit that monitors the voltage at either end of the precharge resistor circuit.

Since the load will have capacitance, I should expect an RC time constant curve on the load of the precharge resistor. I want to use this characteristic to see if the precharge was executed in an appropriate amount of time.

The battery voltage will be 48V. I will use a potential divider to step the 48V to something smaller. However, the problem I am facing is how to do the isolation part of the circuit. I want to isolate the fragile micro-control from the 48V battery. So I need to get the voltage from the buffer to the microcontroller in an isolated manner.

Can someone assist in guiding me?

[image]

UPDATE 2:
[image]

Comment: Two resistors, a capacitor and possibly a Schottky diode?

Comment: @winny going straight into a micro-controller, I don't think so. I need to isolate the output of what you said to the micro, how can I do that?

Comment: Don’t they share ground?

Comment: @winny no they do not, one is GNDS and the other GNDPWR, from the second pic

Comment: How are they related to each other?

Comment: Where does the 12V come from?

Comment: This question feels like going down the rabbit hole. What is the __actual final goal__ of this circuit? Is this inrush protection? Random project to learn electronics? Experimenting with MCU? The reason I am asking is that each of these have their own challenges and simple solutions, and neither looks anywhere close to what you are asking about.

Comment: @Maple please see update 2. The goal is to track the voltage rise as the precharge resistor slowly charges the caps in the load. If the charge time is too long it is a problem, if the charge time is too slow it is also a problem.

Comment: Sorry, you did not get my point. "track the voltage rise" is your intended _solution_, not _the goal_.

Comment: 48 V is low enough to be touched in most jurisdictions, called SELV. Do what everyone else does and skip the isolation unless you can show a real reason not to. "Sensitive MCU" isn't one. "High voltage" isn't one.

Answer (score 0):

The voltage monitoring circuit can in fact be referenced to the battery negative, and there doesn't need to be galvanic isolation. It just needs a current source output for the current sensor.

Something like the following - where VCCS1+Rs act as a CCCS.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpYAMB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

U2 would be a part designed for industrial duty, with overvoltage protection built-in.

IFBK and VFBK need overvoltage protection as well - any small transient suppressor designed for logic inputs will do.

R3 protects from catastrophic failure of VCCS1 - like a short.

VCCS1 can be any of a number of voltage-to-current converter circuits. VCCS1 can be made using a MOS or BJT transistor and a TL071 op-amp. The latter accepts common mode inputs up to positive supply. Cheap. And no need for resistor matching and differential measurements!

U1 could be a 79L12. It dumps a couple mA into VCCLO and that should be OK and decrease the dissipation on U2 a little. Otherwise, D1 would go to the ground plane.

D2 protects the circuit from reverse polarity.

Of course, the current sensor itself could be isolated. Most likely any of the common Hall-effect-based sensors will work - it can be a cheap low-accuracy sensor as is typically used for general-purpose current monitoring. In that case, VCCHI is not needed. R1 and R2 for VFBK can be fairly high values if there's a voltage follower buffering them, so no worry about transients.

In any case R1 and R3 should be a series combination such that the voltage ratings on all resistors add up to 1kV, for example, to stand off against transients. R1 and R3 should also ideally be made of pulse-rated fusible resistors, so that catastrophic events won't destroy the controller.

Comment: How does all of this, assist in tracking the voltage rise, and what is then monitored to determine the voltage rising, so I can see if the rise time is correct or not? U1 is a negative voltage reg, what is the purpose of a negative reg? What does VCCHI and VCCLO do, what are they meant to power?

Comment: So you basically convert the voltage to current, then use an isolated current sensor to measure this current. Then send the output of the isolated current sensor to a microcontroller. Then do some calculations to calculate the voltage.

Comment: Why not just use a potential divider and an AMS1351 IC?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple provided that the two circuits share the same ground.  If nodes GND5 and GNDPWR can be connected together, then it is simply a matter of selecting suitable resistors to bring the two voltages being sensed to within the acceptable input range of the ADC inputs of control IC.

Otherwise, the challenge will be to transmit two (2) analog signals across an isolation barrier, and that is never a trival matter.

Is there any reason that the two circuits cannot share the same ground node?

Comment: The isolation is essential, due to the high voltage battery, I want to keep my sensitive electronics, like the MCU away from the high-voltage battery.

Comment: @JoeyB  I understand your concern, however, it is ill-founded.  Simply connecting the grounds together does not cause the "high voltage" of the battery to damage your MCU.   All circuits that you as a human are going to touch should be connected to **earth** for safety reasons, so it is very likely that the GNDPWR and GND5 will already be connected to earth one way or another for safety, so you may as well make use of that fact and in addition make this an explicit connection in your design.

Comment: To ensure the MCU is not damaged by the battery, all you do is make sure that any voltage from the 48V battery that drives a current into the MCU can only drive a limited current that cannot damage the MCU.  This is done by having sufficient resistance between the battery nodes and the MCU nodes.  You can also put voltage clamps, such as diodes to GND and 3V3 (or 5V) that clamp node voltages to those rails, and have a resistance so that the high votlage drives current into the clamp rather than the MCU input.

Comment: Or you can be 100% and just isolate it using an isolated dc/dc... Why go through all the trouble of calculating those values which as more risk? Because each one of those components you mentioned, resistors, and voltage clamps, come with their own issues when selecting them. You can never take into account all possibilities. Or you can just get a dc/dc isolator which is purpose-built and is only one component. I am not understnding why you would not go down the isolation route to be honest.

Comment: "All circuits that you as a human are going to touch should be connected to earth for safety reasons" So you saying connecting an oscilloscope probe to your circuit and having it plug into mains and earthed is a good idea, and having the circuit connected to your PC thrugh USB? Or should you isolate the USB connection to your laptop...

Comment: @JoeyB  Well, it seems you have taken a somewhat belligerent attitude here.  Why the downvote? 
| You have made 4 consecutive comments without waiting for my response to any.  With regard to your comment #3 above containing: "already a very contradicting statement."  I find this comment confusing - what specific part of my comment is contradictory?

Comment: @JoeyB  And with regard to your comment #4: "delete that comment".  Which specific comment do you want me to delete?

Comment: @JoeyB  I return to the original question I posed in my answer: "Is there any reason that the two circuits cannot share the same ground node?"

Specifically, you did **not** mention **safety** as part of your reason as to why they cannot share the same ground node, yet it seems you are upset now and are asking me to delete something seemingly on the grounds of safety.   So I am confused - what is it that you want me to do??

Comment: I see I did not explicitly say why I wanted it to be isolated. The only reason for the isolation is the safety aspect. I want to have a clear isolation part on the board so I can safely work on the low-voltage side without having to worry about any high-voltage coupling to the low-voltage side. No, I am not upset :). Thank you for providing information on my post!

Comment: @JoeyB  Isolation is not necessarily the safest option for you.  You mentioned scopes: why do you think they are earthed?  Because it is the safest option.  Leaving circuits to "float" to some undefined voltage wrt earth can be dangerous, they can easily accumulate charge causing voltage to rise well above/below earth or the "common" of your sensitive circuit, without you knowing.  The first you know about it is when you hear that classic "tick" indicating a destructive discharge that has possibly zapped your MCU, or when your arm is thrown back involuntarily & hitting the bench, or worse.

Comment: @JoeyB  You don't need total isolation, you just need sufficient impedance to all the "high voltage" nodes to limit the energy to well below destructive/dangerous levels.  Just select suitable resistors, of sufficient voltage rating and have several in series, from the battery nodes to the MCU circuit.   A short from the resistor to "GND" does not cause excessive current.  Also, if a single resistor fails short-circuit then there is still enough remaining resistors to continue to provide current limiting.   It is a common technique employed in literally millions of products globally.

Comment: @JoeyB  When you get time, please remove your down-vote, thank you.

Comment: So when should I isolate my circuits when using a dc battery?

Comment: Depends on:  1. Battery voltage, below 60Vdc is considered safe from electrocution risk, however there is still the risk of high-energy arcs & explosions,hence high impedance is required; 2. The "circuit" function.  There are some circuits that simply cannot be isolated from the battery, for example, cell charge balancing.  There always has to be **some** part of "the circuit" that is connected to the battery, even if that is just the battery side connections of a galvanic isolator. | If "the circuit" is a CSU then I would consider isolation, particularly if the battery voltage exceeds 60Vdc.